# Access object proprieties using Typescript

Tags: javascript

I am studying typescript. I have the next code:

```js
interface Ione {
    person: string;
}
interface Itwo {
    age: number;
}

const obj: Ione | Itwo = {
    person: 'Name',
    age: 45
}

const {person, age} = obj;
```

Trying to destructure  object keys from `obj`, i get the next error: `Property 'person' does not exist on type 'Ione | Itwo'.(2339)`  and `Property 'age' does not exist on type 'Ione | Itwo'.(2339)` .
 NOTE: I need to find a solution for this particular example `const obj: Ione | Itwo` not `const obj: Ione & Itwo`. 
 Question: How to destructure the object in the case described above?

Comment: How about changing `Ione & Itwo` instead of `Ione | Itwo`?

Comment: @RyanLe, `NOTE: I need to find a solution for this particular example const obj: Ione | Itwo not const obj: Ione & Itwo`

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want. your type is `Ione | Itwo` but you need `Ione & Itwo` why? if you can't use `one & Itwo` you may need to use type assertion: `const {person, age} = obj as Ione & Itwo;`

Comment: By declaring `Ione | Itwo` and put `both` of them into the object, you are doing an illegal thing even though typescripts didn't warn you about that. because you can still cast them at the end.

Answer (score 1):

##### The simple answer is that you cannot destructure properties that don't exist in Typescript.

Your only options are to use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types), or [type coercion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

```
const obj: Ione & Itwo = {
    person: 'Name',
    age: 45
}
```

or

```
const { person, age } = obj as Ione & Itwo;
```

Comment: "NOTE: I need to find a solution for this particular example const obj: Ione | Itwo not const obj: Ione & Itwo." OP said. Anyway, even if he said like that, I don't think there is a solution using pipe...

Comment: Yeah, I understand he wants to avoid `Intersection Types`, but that's why I mentioned that it's simply not possible.

Answer (score 0):

To combine 2 interfaces you could write:

```
interface Ione {
    person: string;
}
interface Itwo {
    age: number;
}

interface Mixed extends Ione, Itwo {}

const obj: Mixed = {
    person: 'Name',
    age: 45
}
```